# Magnanimous but in a conceited manner

Tags: single-word-requests

Through the magic of introspection I've discovered something about myself. It doesn't feel pleasant to say but I feel good when I behave magnanimously. And when I say I feel good, I don't mean I feel good because I was nice to someone, it's more like I somehow feel superior to others when I show them generosity.

I realize this incredibly conceited of me but more importantly I am wondering if there is a word for this? Being overly magnanimous to satisfy your own inflated sense of superiority.

Comment: Hmmm,  I like this feeling myself :) However I don't feel superior to any one particular person... I feel superior to a more common behavior.  As far as I am concerned there is room for everyone at the magnanimous top, and we can all feel especially proud of our-selves for that noble behavior. Do you mean you think poorly of the others ... not simply proud of yourself?

Comment: @Tom22 More like pride laced with egotism

Comment: One way I've seen this expressed is with a noun, Lady Bountiful, to show sarcasm, for example, "The minister's wife played Lady Bountiful, giving one sparkly pencil to each child."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone behaving in a ***patronizing*** way might be what you are hoping to describe.  However, they wouldn't be acting magnanimously any more.

Also, many forms of patronizing behavior have nothing to do with forgiveness and generosity central to the common meaning of magnanimous.

> [***patronize*** at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/patronize)
>   ˈpātrəˌnīz,ˈpatrəˌnīz
>   verb
>
> gerund or present participle: patronizing
>
> 1.
>   treat with an apparent kindness that betrays a feeling of superiority.